# Are ruby structs stack allocated?

Tags: ruby, memory-management, struct, callstack

Ruby [structs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Struct.html) are a convenient way to define lightweight data containers. My question is if they are allocated on the heap just like normal objects or on the stack (as in, for instance, C# value types). If they are heap-allocated then are there any performance benefits - or pitfalls - for ruby structs.

Answer (score 4):

C# value types are not stack-allocated. They are sometimes stack-allocated, sometimes not. They are stack allocated when you declare a local value of a value-type type, but not stack-allocated when you declare a class instance field of a value-type type.

Ruby structs are normal Ruby classes, and instances of struct classes are, just like instances of any other classes, allocated on the heap. The only Ruby types that are value types are `FalseClass`, `TrueClass`, `NilClass`, `Fixnum`, and `Symbol`. `Symbol` is special, though, since instances must also be allocated globally in the symbol table while at the same time being value types.